# How to reuse argument from a function?

Tags: javascript, function, scope

I have a function that shows image after input(type=file) loads. I need to save the source attribute of image, so I could use it furthermore.
This is the code:

```
 function readURL(input, callback) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    let reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
      regForm.img.setAttribute('src', e.target.result); // I need to save this somehow, to use it later in a POST Request body.
     }
     reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

Comment: have readURL return a Promise that resolves to e.target.result, inside the onload callback - that promise can be used as often as you'd like now

Comment: Use it where? Use it when?

Comment: @JaromandaX a piece of code, would be great!

Comment: @Quentin let's say in another POST Request function. I want to send `src` of that image to server.

Comment: Why not just call `readURL` again and pass in a different callback? (and actually use a callback). Or submit the file itself instead of converting it to a data URL?

Comment: @Quentin, would be great if you could provide an example.

Comment: You can also read it back from the image you set it on?

Comment: @Nasa, I tried to console log that, but I get blank log.

Comment: That's weird.. reading the data url and displaying the image do work right? how did you try to read it back? anyways, the answer that has been submitted below is a better way to do it

Comment: @Nasa, yes, really weird, I upload the image, works just fine, but when logging the `src`, it's either blank or the link of my localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use promise like this:

```
function readURL(input) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            let reader = new FileReader()
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                regForm.img.setAttribute('src', e.target.result)
                reolve(e.target.result)
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0])
        }
    })
}
```

Whenever you want the source `const src = await readURL(YOUR FILE)`

Comment: yo may want to reject `if (input.files && input.files[0])` is false, or `raeader.onerror`